# Is it possible to download a file from a method that returns a JsonResult?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to download a file from a local server. The method that downloads the file displays an error message if the file could not be found.

This is the code in my view:

```
function download(id) {
            var response = null;
            var fileId = id == null? 0 : id;
            var args = {fileId : fileId };

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Home/DownloadFile',
                    data: args,
                    dataType: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#message").attr('style', 'margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; font-                             weight: bold; color: Red');
                        $("#message").html(data.message);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

<div id="message"></div>
<a class="fileName" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='download(@f.Id)'>@f.Name</a>
```

And this is my controller:

```
public JsonResult DownloadFile(int fileId)
    {
        FileService fileService = new FileService();
        DirectoryService directoryService = new DirectoryService();
        File file = fileService.GetByFileId(fileId);

        bool noError = false;
        string _message = String.Empty;

        if (file == null) 
        {
            _message = "File does not exist";
        }
        else if (System.IO.File.Exists(file.FilePath))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(file.FilePath))
            {
                Stream s = reader.BaseStream;
                byte[] fileData = Utils.ReadStream(s);
                string contentType = Utils.getContentType(file.FileName);

                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file.FileName);
                Response.ContentType = contentType;
                Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);

                noError = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _message = "File \"" + file.FileName + "\" could not be found.";  //File "foo.txt" could not be found
        }

        if (noError)
            _message = String.Empty;

        var data = new { message = _message };
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The odd thing is that the first time I tested this, it worked. I do not remember changing anything, but now the method executes normally, but the file is not downloaded. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: You sure the id passed in is correct? The file is found and the file exists?

Comment: Yes. I'm checking all that with the debugger. My guess is that ajax is stopping my file from being downloaded

Comment: This is NOT the solution you should use, but if you get stuck and there are no other solutions, you can try this: move the file download method to it's on controller/action (non ajaxed). If the file is found, send a redirect to the file download action. Not sure if this will work, but i'm pretty sure it's not the ideal answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You cannot download files with AJAX. Also you cannot have a controller action that returns 2 different things: a file data and JSON. The reason for not being able to download files with AJAX is because even if the request will be sent to the server and the file will arrive up until the client inside your AJAX `success` callback you will get the raw file data passed as parameter but there's not much you could do with it. You cannot save the file on the client computer and you cannot prompt the user for choosing a location where he wants to store the file on his computer.

So if you want to download files use normal HTML links or forms. No AJAX.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought. Do you have any suggestion for what I'm trying to do? Basically, I just want to let the user know if the file is not found in the server/